# Computing the surface between two lines

Tags: matlab, intersection, contour, surface

I have the following figure, where I plotted two surfaces and I wanted to indicate the intersection of both of them. To do that, I did the following:

```
zdiff = z1-z2;
C = contours(x,y,zdiff,[0 0]);
xL = C(1, 2:end);
yL = C(2, 2:end);
zL = interp2(x, y, z1, xL, yL);
line(xL, yL, zL, 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 2,'Linestyle','--'); hold on;
line(xL, yL, zeros(size(zL)), 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 2); hold off;
```

Now, I want to **plot** the vertical surface between the actual intersection (dash line) and its projection over XY (solid line), but I cannot figure out how to do that. Any ideas?

[image: Intersection of both surfaces]

Comment: Do you want to calculate the value of the surface, OR do you want to draw the surface?

Comment: Actually, drawing the surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another really simple option:

```
dist  = (diff(xL).^2+diff(yL).^2).^0.5; %distance between x,y
cdist = [0, cumsum(dist)]; %cumsum of the distance
area  = trapz(cdist,zL); %The area
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant drawing the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculating it manually?

Something like (untested):

```
Area = 0
for i=1:numel(xL)-1
    base = sqrt(   (xL(i)-xL(i+1))^2 + (yL(i)-yL(i+1))^2);
    Area =Area + base * (zL(i) + zL(i+1))/2;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not pretty but its a oneliner it might do the trick. maybe you have to adjust the format as this code is for (1,N) vectors

```
   xL=(1:100); %size 1 100
   yL=(1:100) ;%size 1 100
   zL=rand(1,100);%size 1 100

   line(xL,yL,zL)
   line(xL,yL,zeros(size(zL)))
   hold on 
   surf(repmat(xL,100,1),repmat(yL,100,1),cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) linspace(x,y,100)',zL,zeros(size(zL)),'UniformOutput',false)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xL=sin((1:30)/10);  % Data generation for test only. Use your data
yL=cos((1:30)/10);  % Data generation for test only. Use your data
zL=2+xL.*yL;        % Data generation for test only. Use your data
surf([xL;xL],[yL;yL],[zeros(size(zL));zL]); % plot the surface
```